# FreeRTOS Shared pointer parameter set to 0

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, freertos

I am trying to share data between 2 FreeRTOS tasks. My approach for this is to create a `struct` for the tasks' `pvParameters` that contains a `std::shared_pointer`.

My task creation looks like this:

```
    auto shared_value = std::make_shared<int8_t>(-1);

    auto paramsA = SharedValParams(shared_value);

    xTaskCreate(taskA,
                "Task A",
                4000,
                (void *)&paramsA ,
                1,
                NULL);

    auto paramsB = SharedValParams(shared_value);

    xTaskCreate(taskB,
                "Task B",
                4000,
                (void *)&paramsB,
                1,
                NULL);
```

I'm currently trying to modify this value

```
    void taskA(void *params)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            *((SharedValParams*)params)->shared_val= 5;
            Serial.printf("Shared val is now %d\n",
                 *(*(SharedValParams*)params).shared_val.get());
            vTaskDelay(1000/ portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }
    }
```

The first couple executions of `taskA`, `shared_val` is printed as 5. Great! However, after this `shared_val` is set to `0`, or at least that's what is being printed. I've yet to implement this in taskB, so nothing else accesses or modifies `shared_val`. I'm unsure as to why this is happening, especially when the default value of `shared_val` is -1.

In the future once I resolve this issue, I will surround `shared_val` in a mutex, but for now, I cannot reliably set the value. The motivation behind passing this as a param, is to keep the value scoped between relevant tasks.

Comment: Your `xTaskCreate` doesn't look type-safe.  It will not invoke copy constructors and `shared_ptr` will be unable to do reference counting, so when the original `shared_ptr` instances in the controller thread go out of scope, the `shared_ptr` deallocates the data it is managing.

Comment: To confirm this, use a `shared_ptr` to a class instance where the constructors (include copy constructor) and destructors are all instrumented to print messages.

Comment: The solution is to use `std::thread`, which properly copies the thread parameter objects in a typesafe manner.  If your platform doesn't have a working `std::thread`, you will not be able to use smart pointers for thread parameters.

Comment: If you're on a ARM Cortex-M platform and the object provided by reference is created on main stack, it get's lost/corrupted because FreeRTOS resets the main stack and uses it as ISR stack. You've to use persistent storage (static/heap) for task parameter objects.